# Azure virtual machine billing granularity

Tags: azure, citrix, billing

This is the current billing for a Citrix XenApp virtual machine. I'd like to do some testing by restoring the VM image to a temporary VM which will exist only for a few days.

How will my client be billed for this? I've read it's hourly so a couple of days for the VM alone would cost ~£367.77/30*2?

[image]

Comment: how about asking the support?

Comment: they don't have support - on the basic Azure package

Comment: You can create an estimate using the pricing calculator https://azure.microsoft.com/en-ca/pricing/calculator/

Comment: Doesn't the pricing calculator give monthly costing? My question is whether the costs are granular down to a couple of days, i.e. you create a VM for testing and delete it two days later